# How did they shoot this scene where actors are eating dirt?

Tags: film-techniques, the-way-back

In *The Way Back (2010)*, there is one scene where Mr Smith is shown eating dirt from under his boot.

[image: Picking up dirt]

[image: Eating dirt]

It is continuous shot, no cuts.

Comment: Seems like there's two options... they made clean "dirt"... or he just actually ate dirt. Does it really matter, though?

Comment: Also, you wouldn't [necessarily get ill](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/06/110602162820.htm)l from eating dirt. It *could* be that he just ate a little bit of dirt, like method acting?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The recipe:

You take two cups of flour, 2 eggs and some chocolate milk. You mix the two cups of flour in a bowl together with the eggs. When it's getting a mud like form, you mix in the chocolate milk until you reach the desired dirt color. You can add some sugar, depending on taste.

Cover the paste up and put it in the refrigerator until needed.

Apply to boot with a spatula and preferably walk on a clean floor before ingesting.

Comment: While that does sound tasty, is this a recipe you've created or do you know it's what was used in this film?

Comment: Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: @Paulie_D I asked the actor who played Mr. Smith. And he said, I quote: "You take two cups of flour, 2 eggs and some chocolate milk. You mix the two cups of flour in a bowl together with the eggs. When it's getting a mud like form, you mix in the chocolate milk until you reach the desired dirt color. You can add some sugar, depending on taste.

Cover the paste up and put it in the refrigerator until needed.

Apply to boot with a spatula and preferably walk on a clean floor before ingesting."

Comment: If you can source that comment **with a link** then fine...otherwise it's not proof of anything.

Comment: @stevenvanc, you asked _Ed Harris_?  How?  In person?  By e-mail?  You called him up?